# How do I make PyCharm show code coverage of programs that use multiple processes?

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, pycharm

Let's say I create this simple module and call it MyModule.py:

```
import threading
import multiprocessing
import time

def workerThreaded():
    print 'thread working...'
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'thread complete'

def workerProcessed():
    print 'process working...'
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'process complete'

def main():
    workerThread = threading.Thread(target=workerThreaded)
    workerThread.start()
    workerProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=workerProcessed)
    workerProcess.start()
    workerThread.join()
    workerProcess.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And then I throw this together to unit test it:

```
import unittest
import MyModule

class MyModuleTester(unittest.TestCase):
    def testMyModule(self):
        MyModule.main()

unittest.main()
```

(I know this isn't a good unit test because it doesn't actually TEST it, it just runs it, but that's not relevant to my question)

If I run this unit test in PyCharm with code coverage, then it only shows the code inside the `workerThreaded()` and `main()` functions as being covered, even though it clearly covers the `workerProcessed()` function as well.

How do I get PyCharm to include code that was started in a new process process in its code coverage?  Also, how can I get it to include the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block as well?

I'm running PyCharm 2.7.3, as well as Python 2.7.3.

Answer (score 1):

Coverage.py can measure code run in subprocesses, details are at http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/subprocess.html

Comment: I set the COVERAGE_PROCESS_START environment variable to "/users/username/.coveragerc" and created a sitecustomize.py in a directory listed in my PYTHONPATH with the two lines of code from your page, but PyCharm still isn't showing the code in workerProcessed as being covered.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work with subprocesses, not sure if this will work with threads or with python 2.

Create .covergerc file in your project root

```
[run]
concurrency=multiprocessing
```

Create sitecustomize.py file in your project root

```
import atexit
from glob import glob

import os
from functools import partial
from shutil import copyfile
from tempfile import mktemp


def combine_coverage(coverage_pattern, xml_pattern, old_coverage, old_xml):
    from coverage.cmdline import main
    # Find newly created coverage files
    coverage_files = [file for file in glob(coverage_pattern) if file not in old_coverage]
    xml_files = [file for file in glob(xml_pattern) if file not in old_xml]

    if not coverage_files:
        raise Exception("No coverage files generated!")

    if not xml_files:
        raise Exception("No coverage xml file generated!")

    # Combine all coverage files
    main(["combine", *coverage_files])

    # Convert them to xml
    main(["xml"])

    # Copy combined xml file over PyCharm generated one
    copyfile('coverage.xml', xml_files[0])
    os.remove('coverage.xml')


def enable_coverage():
    import coverage
    # Enable subprocess monitoring by providing rc file and enable coverage collecting
    os.environ['COVERAGE_PROCESS_START'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.coveragerc')
    coverage.process_startup()

    # Get current coverage files so we can process only newly created ones
    temp_root = os.path.dirname(mktemp())
    coverage_pattern = '%s/pycharm-coverage*.coverage*' % temp_root
    xml_pattern = '%s/pycharm-coverage*.xml' % temp_root
    old_coverage = glob(coverage_pattern)
    old_xml = glob(xml_pattern)

    # Register atexit handler to collect coverage files when python is shutting down
    atexit.register(partial(combine_coverage, coverage_pattern, xml_pattern, old_coverage, old_xml))


if os.getenv('PYCHARM_RUN_COVERAGE'):
    enable_coverage()
```

This basically detects if the code is running in PyCharm Coverage and collects newly generated coverage files. There are multiple files, one for the main process and one for each subprocess. So we need to combine them with "coverage combine" then convert them to xml with "coverage xml" and copy the resulted file over PyCharm's generated xml file.

Note that if you kill the child process in you tests coverage.py will not write the data file.

It does not require anything else just hit "Run unittests with Coverage" button in PyCharm.

That's it.